# Fabricjs text select mode or Edit mode

Tags: fabricjs

I can add "i-text".
If I select text, I can delete it using keyboard delete key.
but, i double-click the text and go to edit mode then click delete key its delete.
how can I fix this.
I want to know how to check text is edit mode or selected mode status.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use [textobject.isEditing](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.IText.html#isEditing) to check whether it's in editing mode or not.

Comment: Is this deprecated? Despite being in editing mode, this returns false.

Answer (score 0):

a little late but here is a working example:

```js
$(document).keydown(function ( event )
{
    switch ( event.which )
    {
        case 46:
            if ( ! canvas.getActiveObject() )
            {
                return;
            }

            if ( canvas.getActiveObject().type !== 'textbox' || ! canvas.getActiveObject().isEditing )
            {
                let activeGroup = canvas.getActiveObjects();

                if ( activeGroup )
                {
                    canvas.discardActiveObject();
                    activeGroup.forEach(function ( object )
                    {
                        canvas.remove(object);
                    });
                }
            }
        break;
     }
});
```